# Unit test Hibernate validation error response in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator, spring-boot-test

I am trying to unit test the `JSON` response Spring Boot sends back to the client when validation of a DTO annotated with `@Valid` fails. Using Postman, I get a `JSON` response listing all the validation errors of the DTO. But when I send the same faulty request using `MockMvc` in one of my unit tests, I get an empty string in the response's body. Here's the test code:

```java
@WebMvcTest(ActivationController.class)
class ActivationControllerTest {

    @Test
    void faulty_personal_information_responded_with_400_bad_request() throws Exception {
        // when
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
            post("/activation/personal")
                .param("firstName", "BZ")
                .param("lastName", "")
        ).andReturn().getResponse();

        System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());

        // then
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

The controller code:

```java
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/personal")
public ResponseEntity<?> personalInformation(
        @ModelAttribute @Valid PersonalInfoDTO personalInfoDto
) {
    // todo: further process data
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

The output from `System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());` above is an empty string.

I know I can test if the validation itself is happening as required using `Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();`, then asserting the errors identified by invoking `validator.validate(faultyObject)` but I need to test the `JSON` response I'm getting on Postman. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you manually construct an instance of `MockMvc` or do you inject the auto-configured one?

Comment: Auto-configured.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you find a solution?